# replacing multi-line string with sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

what I have in the logs.

```
    ---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.16 AS SOURCE ADDRESS---
    ---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.16 AS DESTINATION ADDRESS---
    ---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.17 AS SOURCE ADDRESS---
    some output
    ---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.17 AS DESTINATION ADDRESS---
    ---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.18 AS SOURCE ADDRESS---
    some output
    ---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.18 AS DESTINATION ADDRESS---
    ---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.19 AS SOURCE ADDRESS---
```

what is desired

```
    ---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.16 AS SOURCE ADDRESS---
    None
    ---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.16 AS DESTINATION ADDRESS---
    None
    ---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.17 AS SOURCE ADDRESS---
    some output
    ---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.17 AS DESTINATION ADDRESS---
    None
    ---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.18 AS SOURCE ADDRESS---
    some output
    ---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.18 AS DESTINATION ADDRESS---
    None
    ---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.19 AS SOURCE ADDRESS---
    None
```

I tried sed 's:---\n---:----\nNone\n---/:g'  which didn't do it. 
I need to do some replace on all the lines that ends with --- only when the next line begins with ---

Comment: Sed isn't going to, by default, be able to match patterns that span lines. It only reads one newline terminated line of input at a time. You can make it read it more, but at that point you get to the *weird* part of sed.

Comment: Does lines start with `---`  or does it have space in front of `---`,  if there are space like in your example, most answer below does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e ':a;/^---.*---$/{${aNone' -e 'b};n;//!b;iNone' -e 'ba}' file
```

If the current line begins  and ends with `---` and it is the last line of the file, *append* the string `None`. Otherwise, print the current line and fetch the next and if that also begins and ends with `---`, *insert* `None` and repeat.

Answer (score 2):

I'd write

```
awk '
  /^---/ && prev ~ /^---/ {print "None"}
  {print; prev = $0}
  END {if (/^---/) print "None"}
' file
```

A little DRYer

```
awk '
  function none() {if ($0 ~ /^---/ && prev ~ /^---/) {print "None"}}
  {none(); print; prev = $0}
  END {none()}
' file
```

Comment: I like the idea but you forgot the last line :)

Comment: You did forget that line should end with `---`

Comment: well, that's a slight tweak to the regex, should be obvious.

Comment: You'd need to test for `if (prev ~ /^---/)` in the END section for portability instead of `if (/^---/` or `if ($0 ~ /^---/` since the value of $0 in the END is undefined by POSIX and so will have different values (probably the last record read or null) in different awks. Not sure how I'd write `none()` in the second script given that!

Answer (score 2):

You CAN do it with GNU sed (for `-E`, `-z` and recognizing `\n` as a newline char) with:

```
$ sed -Ez 's/(---\n)(---|$)/\1None\n\2/g' file
---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.16 AS SOURCE ADDRESS---
None
---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.16 AS DESTINATION ADDRESS---
None
---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.17 AS SOURCE ADDRESS---
some output
---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.17 AS DESTINATION ADDRESS---
None
---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.18 AS SOURCE ADDRESS---
some output
---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.18 AS DESTINATION ADDRESS---
None
---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.19 AS SOURCE ADDRESS---
None
```

or GNU awk for multi-char RS and gensub():

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{$0=gensub(/(---\n)(---|$)/,"\\1None\n\\2","g")}1' file
---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.16 AS SOURCE ADDRESS---
None
---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.16 AS DESTINATION ADDRESS---
None
---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.17 AS SOURCE ADDRESS---
some output
---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.17 AS DESTINATION ADDRESS---
None
---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.18 AS SOURCE ADDRESS---
some output
---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.18 AS DESTINATION ADDRESS---
None
---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.19 AS SOURCE ADDRESS---
None
```

but I'd highly recommend you use the following POSIX awk instead for portability, not reading the whole file into memory at once, and the ability to trivially enhance it if you need to make any changes:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^---/ { if (NR>1) prt(); hdr=$0; next }
{ txt = txt ORS $0 }
END { prt() }
function prt() {
    print hdr (txt=="" ? ORS "None" : txt)
    hdr = txt = ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.16 AS SOURCE ADDRESS---
None
---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.16 AS DESTINATION ADDRESS---
None
---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.17 AS SOURCE ADDRESS---
some output
---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.17 AS DESTINATION ADDRESS---
None
---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.18 AS SOURCE ADDRESS---
some output
---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.18 AS DESTINATION ADDRESS---
None
---POLICIES WITH 172.25.22.19 AS SOURCE ADDRESS---
None
```

Comment: Does this test if the last three characters are `---` as in OPs request?

Comment: No just the first 3, it's not obvious that he needs it to end with `---` too but obviously trivial to change `/^---/` to `/^---.*---$/` if so.

Comment: That seems to work.   From OPs request:  "I need to do some replace on all the lines that ends with --- only when the next line begins with ---"

Comment: Yeah but I think that's because the OP was trying to come up with a sed solution when that approach would be the obvious one, I don't think it's functionally required. The OP can always correct us though.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk '{
        if($0 ~ /^-{3}/){
            if(header==1){
                print "None"
            }; 
            header = 1
        }else{
            header = 0
        }
     }1
     END{
        if(header){
            print "None"
        }
     }' <input>
```

Shorter :

```
awk '!/^-{3}/{header=0;print;next}header{print "None"}{header=1}1;END{if(header){print "None"}}' <input>
```

Comment: This does not take in request that line should end with `---` and start with `---`.  It gives output even if `---` at end are missnig